# Open Aspx extension website on ubuntu

Tags: linux, firefox, web, mono, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to open .Aspx website from Firefox but getting error.Is there some solution to open Microsoft based website without wine (without wine remember)

Answer (score 1):

.aspx site can be opened successfully on ubuntu. The Microsoft technology that site uses will render in the site's server and you can successfully open the site.

But there may be some activex or silverlight content in the site. There is a solution for silverlight which is monolight but i don't know how to open activex content on linux.